# How should D.N.Angel and A.I. Love You be tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, tags

There are a number of animes/mangas that have periods in their name, such as D.N.Angel and A.I. Love You. There are a few options for tagging them, using D.N.Angel as an example:

- [dnangel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnangel)
- [d-n-angel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-n-angel)
- [dn-angel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dn-angel)

There should probably be some sort of precedent set up so it doesn't have to be asked every time it comes up. Currently, my D.N.Angel question is tagged as [dnangel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnangel) but obviously that can change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend tagging as [d.n.angel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d.n.angel) and [a.i.-love-you](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a.i.-love-you). I checked that this works by editing your post; feel free to revert if you don't agree with this.

Comment: Seems good to me. I didn't think periods would work in tags.

Comment: @kuwaly I don't blame you, I didn't think they would either. I thought we'd be using [d-n-angel] for sure.

Comment: I didn't think it would work either until I remembered that Stack Overflow has plenty of tags with periods.

Comment: [tag:asp.net] fellas :) An SO user would have known

Comment: Should dot-hack be changed to .hack?

Comment: @kuwaly This change was already made. [tag:dot-hack] is a synonym for [tag:.hack] now.

Comment: It does exist. I actually couldn't find .hack before, but I found it.